# How to add numbers in two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, one list is `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`. The second list is `[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]` 
and then I want to `1 + 2 =3 2+ 3 =5`..... finally it becomes a new list : `[[3,5,7],[7,9,11]` and return the new list?

If I have two table, table 1 and table 2, then I create a new table 3 and add the value of each element in table1 to the value of the corresponding element of table2 and store the sum at the same location in table 3

Comment: You use `+`, just like you've suggested. What even is the question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through a list of lists in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151104/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist If I have two table, table 1 and table 2, then I create a new table 3 and add the value of each element in table1 to the value of the corresponding element of table2 and store the sum at the same location in table 3

Comment: You do it in 3 steps: iterate over the lists, add the corresponding values, add sum to new lists. If iterating over the lists ("tables") is the point of confusion, see the dupe target I linked. If constructing the new list is the problem, there's presumably another duplicate that explains.

Comment: (PS if the answer below helps you, use it. From SO's perspective this has been asked before and we'd like to find a link to where it was answered.)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Using list comprehension:

```
add_matrices = lambda m1,m2: [[x+y for x,y in zip(v1,v2)] for v1,v2 in zip(m1,m2)]
add_matrices ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
```

**Option 2:** Using Numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])+np.array([[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
```

Comment: what is the useage of numpy?

Comment: working with numerical data efficiently. read more about it at: http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it or at least vote up