# Why does this iteration over a list of lists not work?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nlp

I am trying to look for keywords in sentences which is stored as a list of lists. The outer list contains sentences and the inner list contains words in sentences. I want to iterate over each word in each sentence to look for keywords defined and return me the values where found.

This is how my token_sentences looks like.
[image]

I took help from this post. [How to iterate through a list of lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151104/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-lists-in-python) However, I am getting an empty list in return.

This is the code I have written.

```
 import nltk
 from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

 text = "MDCT SCAN OF THE CHEST:     HISTORY: Follow-up LUL nodule.   TECHNIQUES: Non-enhanced and contrast-enhanced MDCT scans were performed with a slice thickness of 2 mm.   COMPARISON: Chest CT dated on 01/05/2018, 05/02/207, 28/09/2016, 25/02/2016, and 21/11/2015.     FINDINGS:   Lung parenchyma: There is further increased size and solid component of part-solid nodule associated with internal bubbly lucency and pleural tagging at apicoposterior segment of the LUL (SE 3; IM 38-50), now measuring about 2.9x1.7 cm in greatest transaxial dimension (previously size 2.5x1.3 cm in 2015). Also further increased size of two ground-glass nodules at apicoposterior segment of the LUL (SE 3; IM 37), and superior segment of the LLL (SE 3; IM 58), now measuring about 1 cm (previously size 0.4 cm in 2015), and 1.1 cm (previously size 0.7 cm in 2015) in greatest transaxial dimension, respectively."  

 tokenizer_words = TweetTokenizer()
 tokens_sentences = [tokenizer_words.tokenize(t) for t in 
 nltk.sent_tokenize(text)]

 nodule_keywords = ["nodules","nodule"]
 count_nodule =[]
 def GetNodule(sentence, keyword_list):
     s1 = sentence.split(' ')
     return [i for i in  s1 if i in keyword_list]

 for sub_list in tokens_sentences:
     result_calcified_nod = GetNodule(sub_list[0], nodule_keywords)
     count_nodule.append(result_calcified_nod)
```

However, I am getting the empty list as a result for the variable in count_nodule.

This is the value of first two rows of "token_sentences".

```
token_sentences = [['MDCT', 'SCAN', 'OF', 'THE', 'CHEST', ':', 'HISTORY', ':', 'Follow-up', 'LUL', 'nodule', '.'],['TECHNIQUES', ':', 'Non-enhanced', 'and', 'contrast-enhanced', 'MDCT', 'scans', 'were', 'performed', 'with', 'a', 'slice', 'thickness', 'of', '2', 'mm', '.']]
```

Please help me to figure out where I am doing wrong!

Comment: Can you isolate your issue if it comes from the `nltk` part of your code, or the list of lists iterator part? Also please include the value of `tokens_sentences`

Comment: @Devesh Kumar Singh list of lists iterator part

Comment: Alright, please show us how `tokens_sentences` looks like!

Comment: Added picture of the tokens_sentences

Comment: No please paste the data, not the picture!

Comment: updates with the values of "tokens_sentences"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to remove `s1 = sentence.split(' ')` from `GetNodule` because `sentence` has already been tokenized (it is already a `List`).
2. Remove the `[0]` from `GetNodule(sub_list[0], nodule_keywords)`. Not sure why you would want to pass the first word of each sentence into `GetNodule`!

Answer (score 2):

The error is here:

```
for sub_list in tokens_sentences:
     result_calcified_nod = GetNodule(sub_list[0], nodule_keywords)
```

You are looping over each `sub_list` in `tokens_sentences`, but only passing the first word `sub_list[0]` to `GetNodule`.

This type of error is fairly common, and somewhat hard to catch, because Python code which expects a list of strings will happily accept and iterate over the individual characters in a single string instead if you call it incorrectly. If you want to be defensive, maybe it would be a good idea to add something like

```
assert not all(len(x)==1 for x in sentence)
```

And of course, as @dyz notes in their answer, if you expect `sentence` to already be a list of words, there is no need to `split` anything inside the function. Just loop over the sentence.

```
return [w for w in sentence if w in keyword_list]
```

As an aside, you probably want to `extend` the final result with the list `result_calcified_nod` rather than `append` it.