# Iteration on nested list and generators and yield

Tags: python, iteration, generator

I was looking at creating a simple generator to sum the values of two list with nested values.
Using from stack this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014386/461887 and this answer [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

So I created 2 lists

```
a = ([1, 2], [2, 3])

b = ([3, 4], [5, 6])
```

created a generator which errored.

```
In [10]: def sumNest(item1, item2):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         for i in iter(item1):
    ...:             for j in iter(item2):
    ...:                 yield i + j
    ...:     except TypeError:
    ...:         yield item
    ...:
```

I can create it without error but it doesn't work(in the way I expect).

```
In [14]: def sumNest(item1, item2):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         for i in iter(item1):
    ...:             for j in iter(item2):
    ...:                 k = (i + j)
    ...:                 yield k
    ...:     except TypeError:
    ...:         yield item
    ...:
```

Result of my use expecting the summed output.

```
In [17]: sumNest(a, b)
Out[17]: <generator object sumNest at 0x7f313e6e74b0>

In [18]: answer = sumNest(a, b)

In [19]: answer
Out[19]: <generator object sumNest at 0x7f313e6e7230>

In [20]: print answer
<generator object sumNest at 0x7f313e6e7230>

In [21]: answer(a, b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-badcb4bdaf5d> in <module>()
----> 1 answer(a, b)

TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

Which led me to go back a bit and get this result where instead of addition of lists as expected I ended up with concatentation.

```
a = ([1, 2], [2, 3])

b = ([3, 4], [5, 6])

for i in a:
    ...:     for j in b:
    ...:         print(i + j)
    ...:         
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Now thats a nice result, but not again expected(addition expected) so a result like:

```
([4, 6], [7, 9])
```

What is it that I am not getting about iteration, lists and yeild that I need to?

Comment: Your first example misspelled `yield`. Neither example flattens the lists.

Comment: fixed yield in editor and question

Comment: You still left in the `SyntaxError` exception, which was caused by the misspelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator object needs to be *looped over*:

```
for summed in sumNest(a, b):
    print summed
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on a generator to get *one* value from it.

Your first example had a syntax error, because you misspelled `yield`. Your exception handler tries to `yield item`, but the function doesnt actually define that name.

Note that neither of your solutions flattens the lists, you are still 'summing' tuples.

Working example:

```
>>> a = ([1, 2], [2, 3])
>>> b = ([3, 4], [5, 6])
>>> def summedProduct(iter1, iter2):
...     for i in iter(iter1):
...         for j in iter(iter2):
...             yield i + j
... 
>>> for summed in summedProduct(a, b):
...     print summed
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

If instead you wanted to flatten the lists, flatten them *first*, then `zip()` the flattened results together to sum:

```
def summedNested(nested1, nested2):
    flattened1 = (v for nested in nested1 for v in nested)
    flattened2 = (v for nested in nested2 for v in nested)
    for i, j in zip(flattened1, flattened2):
        yield i + j
```

Demo:

```
>>> def summedNested(nested1, nested2):
...     flattened1 = (v for nested in nested1 for v in nested)
...     flattened2 = (v for nested in nested2 for v in nested)
...     for i, j in zip(flattened1, flattened2):
...         yield i + j
... 
>>> for summed in summedNested(a, b):
...     print summed
... 
4
6
7
9
```

Comment: @Martjin Pieters    So I searched for flatten lists, but it still just joins them. not add a[0][0] + b[0][0] and so on. reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,(a, b))
Out[27]: ([1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]) from answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/461887

Comment: actually, what would the expected outcome be for summing `a` and `b`?

Comment: So for `[1, 2] + [3, 4]`, what would the expected sum be? `[4, 6]`? Or `10`?

Comment: Or did you expect to `map(sum, zip([1, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6]))`, so `[4, 6, 7, 9]`?

Comment: @Martjin Pieters.   Correct I expected to receive the result the combination of map sum & zip provided

Comment: @Martjin Pieters.   Does that mean though if I had 10 lists to flatten I would need to create flatten1, flaaten2, flatten3 etc?

Comment: No, you can flatten lists in a loop too, and delegate flattening to a function if needed.

Answer (score 2):

`answer` is generator object, you can make (generate) list from it:

```
result = list(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply calling a generator will give you a generator object. You need to iterate it or use `next` function with it, to get the values. For example,

```
next(sumNest(a, b))
```

would have worked for you. Or iterating with a loop

```
for item in sumNext(a, b):
    print item
```

For example

```
def sumNest(item1, item2):
  try:
      for i in iter(item1):
          for j in iter(item2):
              k = (i + j)
              yield k
  except TypeError:
      yield item1

print next(sumNest([1, 2], [3, 4]))
print
for item in sumNest([1, 2], [3, 4]):
    print item,
```

**Output**

```
4

4 5 5 6
```

And when you say, `I created 2 lists`

```
a = ([1, 2], [2, 3])
b = ([3, 4], [5, 6])
```

you created `tuples` not `lists`.

Comment: shouldn't the output 4 5 5 6 have been 4 6 7 9 being the addition of the two lists at their matching indexes.