# How do I iterate over estimators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

Given an [ensemble estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble), I would like to iterate over the contents of its `estimators_` field.

The problem is that the field can have a *very* different structure.

E.g., for a [`GradientBoostingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) it is a rank-2 `numpy.ndarray` (so I can use [`nditer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html)) while for a [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) it is a simple `list`.

Can I do better than this:

```py
import numpy as np
def iter_estimators(estimators):
    if isinstance(estimators, np.ndarray):
        return map(lambda x: x[()], np.nditer(estimators, flags=["refs_ok"]))
    return iter(estimators)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use `np.asarray` to conveniently ensure the object is an ndarray. Then use `ndarray.flat` to get an iterator over the flattened array.

```
>>> estimators = model.estimators_
>>> array = np.asarray(estimators)
>>> iterator = array.flat
>>> iterator
<numpy.flatiter at 0x7f84f48f8e00>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `numpy`-agnostic solution is

```py
def iter_nested(obj):
    """Iterate over all iterable sub-objects.
    https://stackoverflow.com/q/58615038/850781"""
    try:
        for o1 in obj:
            for o2 in iter_nested(o1):
                yield o2
    except TypeError:           # ... object is not iterable
        yield obj
```

See also

- [Iterating through list of list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6340351/850781)
- [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/850781)
- [iterate python nested lists efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17014211/850781)