# How to use list values as range?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers and a QTableWidget populated with 33 rows.

My list is like this (which corresponds to the rows in the QTableWidget):

```
my_list = [15, 14, 1, 2, 1]
```

I would like to extract information from the table by the number of rows.

For example, I want to loop through the table for the first 15 rows, then the next 14 rows, then the next 1 row etc. So at the moment, I'm using:

```
my_list = [15, 14, 1, 2, 1]

for row in range(15):
    # Do something

for row in range(15,29)
    # Do something

for row in range(29,30)
    # Do something

...
```

As the values in the list (and the number of items) can change, what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get your pairs an use them for `range()`:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [15, 14, 1, 2, 1]

top = list(np.cumsum(my_list))
bottom = list(np.subtract(np.cumsum(my_list),my_list))

pairs = zip(bottom,top)
ranges = iter([range(x[0], x[1]) for x in pairs])
```

Now, you can just go:

```
for item in next(ranges):
```

**EDIT #1**

If your `# Do something` is always different you can use:

```
for row in next(ranges):
    # Do something

for row in next(ranges):
    # Do something
```

**EDIT #2**

If you your `#Do something` is always the same you can go:

```
for item in my_list:
    for row in next(ranges):
        # Do something
```

Comment: When I use `for item in next(ranges):`, it only does this for the first 15 items. Am I supposed to use something else?

Comment: See the edit. I understood you are changing the operation for each range.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, thanks! In the question, I mentioned 5 items in the list so I would have to use `for row in next(ranges):` 5 times. If I have 3 items in the list, I would have to use `for row in next(ranges):` 3 times. Basically I am running a GIS plugin and so the number of items in the list can vary. Is there a method to accomodate this change without me having to _hardcode_ `for row in next(ranges):` x times? I.e. can it be done in a single loop?

Comment: Made another edit in case your `# Do something` is always the same.

Comment: Yes, I was about to make a comment about using a nested `for` loop as described in [Python - Iterating through list of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340351/python-iterating-through-list-of-list)). Now it works perfectly, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by using index of lists

```
for row in range (my_list[0]):
    print "abc"
for row in range (my_list[1]):
    print "bc"
for row in range (my_list[2]):
    print "ac"
for row in range (my_list[3]):
    print "amc"
for row in range (my_list[4]):
    print "c"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the idea is that the number of items in the list can change (i.e. I have shown `5` but it could also be `3`). I'm looking for a more generic way instead of _hardcoding_ it :)