# Creating a float in a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects,

```
l = (('a1', 1.96256684), ('b3', 1.36), ('e2', 0.5715))
```

I want to be able to format the numbers to a certain number of decimal places (4) in order to get an output like

```
a1 1.9626 b3 1.3600 e3 0.5715
```

I tried the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197686) (using isalpha) but get the error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

I'm wondering if it's because the alphabetic letters have numbers attached to them? But then I would think it would just return False instead of giving me an error.

Thank you for any help or adivce

Comment: Can you upload your code? You could be using isalpha on the tuple instead of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to format the strings using `.format`.

```
>>> '{:0.4f}'.format(1.36)
'1.3600'
>>> '{:0.4f}'.format(1.96256684)
'1.9626'
```

The full code could look something like:

```
' '.join('{} {:0.4f}'.format(*t) for t in l)
```

Comment: `' '.join('{0[0]} {0[1]:0.4f}'.format(t) for t in l)` also works and avoids the tuple unpacking, but I don't like it as much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Print statement will join with spaces anyway, so you can unpack the args with a splat:

```
>>> print(*(f'{s} {f:.4f}' for s,f in l))
a1 1.9626 b3 1.3600 e2 0.5715
```

This uses the [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) feature, new in Python 3.6.

Comment: You might want to point out t hat this is python3.6+ only -- And you might want to mention that you are using f-strings.  I appreciate their use, but it's probably good to give people something to google to find out more :-).

Comment: @mgilson  Added.  Feel free to edit my post directly next time.