# How to iterate through a list that contains lists in python?

Tags: python, list, loops

I would like to know how i can iterate through a list containing lists in python, however i would like to use the for loop method that uses index rather than iterating the normal way in python. is it possible to do that?

here is the python code:

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

def flatten(my_lists):
  results = []
  for outer in range(len(my_lists)):
    for inner in range(len(outer)):
      results.append(lists[outer][inner])
  return results

print flatten(n)
```

this is the error I get in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in flatten
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

what is the error in my code ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share me what is the output that you are expecting

Comment: How about https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain ?

Comment: Are you asking how to flatten a list of lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: `outer` is an `int`, so you need `for inner in range(len(my_list[outer]))`

Comment: Could you start by replacing : for outer in range(len(my_lists)) -> for outer in my_lists

Comment: "I would like to use the for loop method that uses index...". Why? You're not using the index for anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through list of list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340351/iterating-through-list-of-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

`outer` and `inner` are both `ints`. Thus, `len(outer)` is bound to fail:

```
results = []
  for outer in range(len(my_lists)):
    # you need the length of the list in position 'outer', not of 'outer' itself
    for inner in range(len(my_lists[outer])):  
      results.append(my_lists[outer][inner])
  return results
```

It is easier not to use indexes at all:

```
results = []
  for lst in my_lists:
    for x in lst:  
      results.append(x)
    # Or without inner loop
    # results.extend(lst)
  return results
```

Moreover, for flattening a list of lists, there are many well-documented approaches, a straightforward one being a nested comprehension like:

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
flat = [x for lst in n for x in lst]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

For more, you can refer to [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) and [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Here the loop with indexes using enumerate.

```
n = [[8, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

def flatten(my_lists):
  results = []
  for idx, outer in enumerate(my_lists):
    for idx2, inner in enumerate(outer):
      results.append(my_lists[idx][idx2])
  return results

print flatten(n)
```

idx and idx2 are the current index of the for loops

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, there is the standard library solution using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> print(list(itertools.chain(*n)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Or (possibly) more explicitly

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> print(list(chain.from_iterable(n)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you just need the flattened 'list' to be iterable, you can omit the `list` call and use the returned `itertools.chain` object.

```
>>> chain.from_iterable(n)
<itertools.chain object at 0x7f2ecc05f668>
```