# Iterating through list of lists

Tags: python, list

i have list of lists, i need via Python iterate through each string ,remove spaces (strip) and save list into new list.

E.g. original list:
org = [ [' a ','b '],['c ',' d '],['e ',' f'] ]

Expecting new list:
new = [ ['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'] ]

I started with below code, but no idea how to add stripped objects into new list of lists. new.append(item) - create simple list without inner list.

`new = []
for items in org:
  for item in items:
    item= item.strip()
    new.append(item)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through list of list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340351/iterating-through-list-of-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like -

```
new = []
for items in org:
  new.append([])
  for item in items:
    item= item.strip()
    new[-1].append(item)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a nested list comprehension that strips each word in each sub-list:

```
new = [[s.strip() for s in l] for l in org]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
org = [ [' a ','b '],['c ',' d '],['e ',' f'] ]
new = []
temp = []

for o in org:
    for letter in o:
        temp.append(letter.strip())
    new.append(temp)
    temp = []
```

Result:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for any list depth:

```
orig = [[' a', 'b '], ['c ', 'd '], ['e ', ' f']]

def worker(alist):

    for entry in alist:
        if isinstance(entry, list):
            yield list(worker(entry))
        else:
            yield entry.strip()

newlist = list(worker(orig))

print(orig)
print(newlist)
```