# list comprehension remove 2d list (sublist) from list if length is less than 7

Tags: python

How do I remove sublist from 2d list with list comprehension if string length is greater than 7? I only know how to do it in regular single dimension list.

Effort:

```
simple_list=['apple', 'banana', 'cantaloupe', 'durian']
mylist=[['apple'], ['banana'], ['cantaloupe'], ['durian']]
short_list = [blist for blist in simple_list if len (blist) <= 7]
```

Want:

```
short_list=[['apple'], ['banana'], ['durian']]
```

Comment: You cannot remove with list comprehension - but you can make _another_ list with the unwanted strings removed. Also, do not use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: What if you have `['cantaloupe', 'pear']`? Why do you need list of lists?

Comment: @OneCricketeer how about "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_, and the _shortest code necessary_ to reproduce the problem."

Comment: @OneCrickteer It is to me. Zero-effort questions take time away from the genuine ones that do need help. You’re entitled to your opinion and not required to vote.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Updated the question now. I only know how to do it with regular list. I don't want to reduce 2d list into 1d list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6340351/839733

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yea sure I can reduce 2d list into 1d list and or use a loop. But the question here is how to do it with list comprehension without having to reduce the list from 2d into 1d. I think the question is specific on point and fully valid and should remain open.

Comment: With your edit, what is the purpose of `mylist`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer knew only how to comprehend simple_list. mylist is what I have and wanted to comprehend but did'nt know how. mylist will be used to add more data like weight, etc. and I liked it structured the way it is as 2d list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each value in the list, return it, if all the elements of the sublist have length less-than-or-equal-to 6

```
[x for x in mylist if all(len(y) <= 6 for y in x)]
```

You can also create a list from the singular string elements, but unclear why you'd want this

```
>>> simple_list=['apple', 'banana', 'cantaloupe', 'durian']
>>> short_list = [[blist] for blist in simple_list if len (blist) <= 7]
>>> short_list
[['apple'], ['banana'], ['durian']]
```

Comment: yes this is similar to what I want. don't want to reduce 2d list into 1d list.